# unzip error: End-of-central-directory signature not found. Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive

Tags: github, unzip, git-lfs

Zip file were download from github. However, I got an error when I tried to unzip this file. The size of  file downloaded is only 1KB, while it should be 175MB.
Any clue how to fix it?

```
[abc@login01 ~]$ git clone https://github.com/ahmetrifaioglu/DEEPScreen.git
Cloning into 'DEEPScreen'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2641, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2641/2641), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2554/2554), done.
remote: Total 5683 (delta 76), reused 2630 (delta 73), pack-reused 3042
Receiving objects: 100% (5683/5683), 117.89 MiB | 268.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1916/1916), done.
Updating files: 100% (2139/2139), done.
```

I tried to decompress this file, but got an error:

```
[abc@login01 trainingFiles]$ unzip chembl_23_chemreps.txt.zip 
Archive:  chembl_23_chemreps.txt.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of chembl_23_chemreps.txt.zip or
        chembl_23_chemreps.txt.zip.zip, and cannot find chembl_23_chemreps.txt.zip.ZIP, period.
```

The contents of file "chembl_23_chemreps.txt.zip" are as follows:

version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:00bdd28bc6d3add8795150538dff4e17f4852d41744a8e69631c56f4a3bc33f7
size 164256561

Machine: Centos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repository is using Git LFS to store large objects.  This file is a Git LFS pointer file that is used to stand in for the real large object in the repository, since the large object is not stored outside the repository.

You need to install Git LFS, probably from EPEL, and then run `git lfs install`.  At that point, Git LFS should run automatically on new repositories.

To fix your existing repository, run `git lfs pull` and it will pull down the files and check them out properly.

Comment: A new error occurred.
 
```batch response: This repository is over its data quota. Account responsible for LFS bandwidth should purchase more data packs to restore access.
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'https://github.com/ahmetrifaioglu/DEEPScreen.git/info/lfs'
```

Comment: GIt LFS download bandwidth is metered for GitHub; an account gets 1 GB free per month.  The owner needs to add a data pack or wait for a new month.

Comment: Can I only contact the author to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes.  You cannot purchase data packs for another account.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is exactly what it says. Unzip can't find the line of code that signals the end of the archive, so either:

```
1. The archive is corrupt.
2. It is not a .zip archive.
3. There are more than 1 parts to the archive, but that doesn't seem possible to me. You should try the other mirror too. It worked for me.
```